# How to build and install MongoDB C++ driver on Ubuntu 13.04 x86?

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb

I am trying to build from source the MongoDB C++ driver on Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64.
When i run:

```
$ scons
```

everything builds as expected. I can also see the mongoclient.a has been built.
However, according to the documentation, I need to do 'sudo scons install' once everything is built, and that doesn't seem to work. I am not really proficient in scons, so I cannot pinpoint the problem.

```
$ sudo scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_system-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for sasl_version_info(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in C library sasl2... (cached) no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `install' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

$ sudo scons install --prefix=/usr/local
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ library boost_system-mt... (cached) yes
Checking for sasl_version_info(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in C library sasl2... (cached) no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `install' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: It looks like the scons install is succeeding. What issue are you seeing?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903407/2254322) is an answer to a related question. This may be helpful for you!